# Wordpress WooCommerce Product Page Template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I just setup WooCommerce on my wordpress site:

http://artendijen.com/product/test-product/

I am not a fan of the template where it has the description and additional information below and in tabs, I would like the have the description and additional information to the right of the product image. Is there a setting I missed or will I have to edit it via CSS myself?

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting for layout in WooCommerce.  If you can do what you need to do with CSS then thats great.  Otherwise, you will need to use hooks and actions in your functions.php to move things around.  You can also overwrite woocommerce template files by copying them to your template with the same structure and file names you find in the WooCommerce plugin.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/